# Xcode 7 ValidateEmbeddedBinary error Could not read data in foo-WatchKit-App.app

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors, watchkit, xcode7

I am trying to do a full build on an iOS App with a WatchKit App as well.

When compiling the full project for Archive I am seeing the following

```
ValidateEmbeddedBinary DerivedData/lifa93/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/lifa93Dev/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/lifa93.app/Watch/lifa93-WatchKit-App.app
    cd /Users/lordandrei/Projects/git/X7/lifa93
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    builtin-embeddedBinaryValidationUtility /Users/lordandrei/Projects/git/X7/lifa93/DerivedData/lifa93/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/lifa93Dev/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/lifa93.app/Watch/lifa93-WatchKit-App.app -signing-cert *9F…FB* -info-plist-path /Users/lordandrei/Projects/git/X7/lifa93/DerivedData/lifa93/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/lifa93Dev/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/lifa93.app/Info.plist

error: warning: Could not read data in /Users/lordandrei/Projects/git/X7/lifa93/DerivedData/lifa93/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/lifa93Dev/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/lifa93.app/Watch/lifa93-WatchKit-App.app
```

I have tried:

- toggling between Debug and Release
- toggling No Install and No Validate.
- revoking and replacing all profiles (Signing, adhoc, dist)

So far nothing has made a dent.

Suggestions welcome as I am in a holding pattern trying to build.

```
Xcode: Version 7.0 beta 3 (7A152u)
iOS: 9.0 beta 3 (13A4293g)    
Radar: 21975256
```

Comment: There can be lots of issues at play here, but for WatchKit I found that the Bundle ID often causes many obscure issues. Are your bundle ids for app, watchkit app, and watchkit extension formatted as: `com.example.app`, `com.example.app.watchkitapp`, and `com.example.app.watchkitapp.watchkitextension`? If not, try seeing if it helps to change them to that format.

Comment: Did you try cleaning your project(deleting `/Users/lordandrei/Projects/git/X7/lifa93/DerivedData/lifa93/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/lifa93Dev/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/lifa93.app`) and then building again? And make sure `builtin-embeddedBinaryValidationUtility` path exists

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue when I was trying to build to my iPhone 6+ and Watch. I had just re-installed Xcode 7 Beta because I accidentally deleted one of the needed frameworks. I tried building several times and received the same "Could not read data..." error. I finally built to the simulator successfully, **AND THEN** built to both devices and it worked.

My issue now is that builds to Apple Watch seem to take forever to run or pass "Attaching...".

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exact reason of your problem, but I created new project that includes WatchKit App target as well. And it works fine, no problems with building process.
I am using Xcode 7 beta (7A120f).

That's why I propose 3 potential ways to resolve the issue:
 **1.** Create new new project from scratch and migrate source and resource files from your current project to new one. I had similar problems (it wasn't related to WatchKit app) previously and this trick helped me.
 **2.** Install latest version of Xcode. [Xcode 7 beta 4](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/) is released on 21st of July.
 **3.** Install Xcode (7A120f). This is version that I am using, you are using different one. I don't think that it will help, but who knows.

Comment: This answer isn't really offering a solution to the problem. Starting a new project from scratch won't help you avoid the problem in the future. Asking someone to install a beta version of the IDE makes it impossible for the user to release his app through the app store.

Comment: Apple Beta software strictly CANNOT be used to release iOS or watch OS or mac OS apps.